# Can't connect to phpmyadmin, can't start MySQL

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, localhost

I'm trying to access PHPMyAdmin in my localhost, but when I write down the username and password, it gives this message:

```
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
```

If i write "mysql" on terminal, it shows me this:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I've looked up the solution for this, but what I encountered was to check the "var/log/mysql/error.log". I did that, and that file is empty.
I have no idea what I have to do here and it seems none of the solutions I found on the internet helped me on this one.
I tried re-installing MySQL but it didn't change anything

If i try to "sudo service mysql start", it shows me this:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

systemctl status mysql.service:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-12-21 15:01:42 -03; 3min 54s ago
Process: 24948 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dez 21 15:01:42 eduardo-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
dez 21 15:01:42 eduardo-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
dez 21 15:01:42 eduardo-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
dez 21 15:01:42 eduardo-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dez 21 15:01:42 eduardo-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

journalctl -xe:

```
-- 
-- A unidade mysql.service concluiu o desligamento.
dez 21 15:01:42 eduardo-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
dez 21 15:01:42 eduardo-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
dez 21 15:01:42 eduardo-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A unidade mysql.service falhou
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A unidade mysql.service falhou.
-- 
-- O resultado é failed.
dez 21 15:01:43 eduardo-System-Product-Name gnome-terminal-[23942]: g_menu_insert_item: assertion 'G_IS_MENU_ITEM (item)' failed
dez 21 15:01:49 eduardo-System-Product-Name kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:18:9c:27:4f:4e:71:08:00 SRC=1>
dez 21 15:03:54 eduardo-System-Product-Name kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:18:9c:27:4f:4e:71:08:00 SRC=1>
dez 21 15:05:04 eduardo-System-Product-Name kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:18:9c:27:4f:4e:71:08:00 SRC=1>
dez 21 15:05:34 eduardo-System-Product-Name gnome-terminal-[23942]: g_menu_insert_item: assertion 'G_IS_MENU_ITEM (item)' failed
dez 21 15:05:41 eduardo-System-Product-Name gnome-terminal-[23942]: g_menu_insert_item: assertion 'G_IS_MENU_ITEM (item)' failed
lines 2441-2464/2464 (END)
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A unidade mysql.service concluiu o desligamento.
dez 21 15:01:42 eduardo-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
dez 21 15:01:42 eduardo-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
dez 21 15:01:42 eduardo-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A unidade mysql.service falhou
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A unidade mysql.service falhou.
-- 
-- O resultado é failed.
dez 21 15:01:43 eduardo-System-Product-Name gnome-terminal-[23942]: g_menu_insert_item: assertion 'G_IS_MENU_ITEM (item)' failed
dez 21 15:01:49 eduardo-System-Product-Name kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:18:9c:27:4f:4e:71:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=20290 PROTO=2 
dez 21 15:03:54 eduardo-System-Product-Name kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:18:9c:27:4f:4e:71:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=20298 PROTO=2 
dez 21 15:05:04 eduardo-System-Product-Name kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:18:9c:27:4f:4e:71:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=20304 PROTO=2 
dez 21 15:05:34 eduardo-System-Product-Name gnome-terminal-[23942]: g_menu_insert_item: assertion 'G_IS_MENU_ITEM (item)' failed
dez 21 15:05:41 eduardo-System-Product-Name gnome-terminal-[23942]: g_menu_insert_item: assertion 'G_IS_MENU_ITEM (item)' failed
```

Comment: This is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65397632/phpmyadmin-not-working-and-cant-start-mysql why did you delete it and reask it?

Comment: because no one helped me there :(

Comment: Please read [help] and learn about the purpose of the site. Stack Overflow is not a personal help desk. Do not expect to receive an answer within one day or even one year. Please do not reask the same question as this will result in a question ban or even suspension.

Comment: i never said that it is, i just thought that the question went by and no one saw it.

Comment: About 20 people saw it. But if you delete then no one else will see it and you are hurting yourself. If you think that not enough people opened your question it might be that not many people are interested in this question. You can try to edit and make it more interesting.

Comment: lesson learned, thanks